# Consistency of a matrix - Is my solution correct?

Tags: calculus, matrices

Doing some past exam question, so no solutions to refer to and my exam is in two days, so if someone could please check if my solution is accurate, it would be great! Thanks in advance for your time and attention :)

Given are the matrix A and the vector b is follows:

$$A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -2 & 3 \\
    2 & 1 & 1 \\
    2 & u & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$  $$
    b= \begin{pmatrix}
    -4 \\
    2\\
    v \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
(u, v are real parameters).

> (a) Determine for which values of parameters u, v does the system Ax =
>   b have
>
> - a unique solution;
> - no solution;
>
>   - infinitely many solutions.

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&-2&3&-4\\
  2&1&1&2\\
  1&u&2&v
\end{array}
\right] $$

using Gaussian elimination, we obtain: 
$R2+(-2)R1$ & $R3+(-1)R1$

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&-2&3&-4\\
  0&5&-5&10\\
  0&u+2&-1&v+4
\end{array}
\right] $$

using, $R3 +(-1)((u+2)/5)$, we get:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&-2&3&-4\\
  0&5&-5&10\\
  0&0&u+1&v-2u
\end{array}
\right] $$

1) no solution (aka the system is inconsistent), when $v-2u\not=0$ but $u=-1$

2) unique solution when: $v\not=2u$ and $u\not=-1$

3) general solution when: $v=2u$ and $u=-1$

> (b) Give the general solution in the case of infinitely many
>   solutions.

Set: $x3=t$, t e R

$R2: x2= 2+ t$

$R1: x1=8-t$

Comment: Your first step already seems to be wrong: in both cases you add $\;(-2)R_1\;$ to $\;R_2\;$ **and also** to $\;R_3\;$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check carefully your steps:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -2 & 3&|&-4 \\
    2 & 1 & 1&|&2 \\
    2 & u & 2&|&v \\
    \end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-2R_1\\R_3-2R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -2 & 3&|&-4 \\
    0 & 5 & -5&|&10 \\
    0 & u+2 & -4&|&v+8 \\
    \end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2\cdot\frac15}\longrightarrow$$$${}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -2 & 3&|&-4 \\
    0 & 1 & -1&|&2 \\
    0 & u+2 & -4&|&v+8 \\
    \end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-(u+2)R_2}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -2 & 3&|&-4 \\
    0 & 1 & -1&|&2 \\
    0 & 0 & u-2&|&v-2u+4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Check now what happens if $\;u=2\,,\,\,v\neq0\;$, or if $\;u\neq2\,,\,\,v\neq2u-4\;$ and etc....

Comment: Oh, my bad! I have mistakenly written the starting matrix here... But thank you for your time regardless, looks like my procedure at least should be accurate :)